# Is p(x) reducible over the rings R?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Is $p(x) = x^4+2x-2$ reducible in any of the following rings: $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{F_9}$ ?

How do you show this for all the individual rings?

Comment: Well the cases of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are easy (irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ have degree at most $2$, and for $\mathbb{C}$ degree at most $1$).

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Why is that true?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed and is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$. It is also a degree 2 extension of $\mathbb{R}$. If $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ strictly larger than $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}(\alpha)=\mathbb{C}$ and a basis over $\mathbb{R}$ is $\{1,\alpha\}$. Thus $\alpha^2=a+b\alpha$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, meaning the irreducible polynomial was quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $\mathbb{Q}$ apply Eisenstein's criterion. In R, the degree of an irreducible polynomial is atmost $2$ and in C, it is atmost $1$.

Comment: What about the finite field?

Comment: I am thinking about it.

Comment: Well, there is no root (try them all, e.g.), so suppose it's a product of 2 quadratics and rule that out, case by case. It's a bit tedious. Berlekamp would show it, probably.